# uninstall and install C# application in VS2010 cannot be executed in expected order

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I am trying to update a C# application published by VS2010 on IIS7.5.

I need to uninstall it and then install a new one. 
If I ran the code in debug mode, it worked well. 
But, if I ran it in release without debug mode. I got error of

```
Another version of the product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/remove programs on the control panel.
```

I found the reason is that "install" started when "uninstall" is still not finished. How to make sure that the "uninstall" is finished before "install" started ? I used **WaitForExit**() (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx) but, **after uninstall, the "install" was not executed**.

The code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace msiexec_uninstall_install
{
   class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {

         var p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("msiexec", "/uninstall http://MyServer/MyApp.msi");

         p.WaitForExit();

         Console.WriteLine("after uninstall");

         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("msiexec", "/i http://myServer/MyApp_new.msi");
         Console.WriteLine("after install");
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your installation takes longer than it takes to finish your Main program, you won't see it.
Try adding `WaitForExit();` for your installation as well.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var uninstallProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("msiexec", "/uninstall http://MyServer/MyApp.msi");
    uninstallProcess.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine("after uninstall");

    var installProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("msiexec", "/i http://myServer/MyApp_new.msi");
    installProcess.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine("after install");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

That way your Main method will only end after installation is complete.  To be on the safe side, you can even add some timeout for `WaitForExit()`:

```
installProcess.WaitForExit(10000); //10 sec
```